# Botón alineado en la parte inferior de v-card en Vuetify

Tags: css, html5, vue.js, vuetify

Trabajando en Vuetify, quiero posicionar el v-btn en la parte inferior del v-card, al tener varios v-cards ahora aparece cada uno a una altura, debido a que no todos tienen los mismos datos y hay datos vacíos.

```html
<v-col v-for="t in info" :key="t.id" cols="12" sm="12" md="6" lg="6" xl="3">
    <v-card height="100%" elevation="3" class='rounded-0'>
        <v-container>
            <v-row dense>
                <v-col cols="12 my-0 py-0">
                    <span class='text-body-2 font-weight-bold ma-0 pa-0'> {{t.titulo}} </span>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row dense>
                <v-col cols="12 my-0 py-0">
                    <span class='text-body-2 ma-0 pa-0'> {{t.subtitulo}} </span>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row dense>
                <v-col cols="12 my-0 py-0">
                    <span class='text-caption ma-0 pa-0'> {{t.texto1}} </span>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-row dense>
                <v-col cols="12 my-0 py-0">
                    <span class='text-caption ma-0 pa-0'> {{t.texto2}} </span>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-card-actions class="px-0">
                <v-btn small color="blue-grey" class="white--text" @click='funcion(t)'> <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon></v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-container>
    </v-card>
</v-col>
```

¿Cuál es la manera de posicionar el botón siempre en la misma posición, en esta caso, al final, del v-card?
He visto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703740/how-to-bottom-align-button-in-card-irrespective-of-the-text-in-vuetify pero no lo consigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No funciona la solución de la respuesta que compartes de la versión en inglés de SO, debido a que su versión del componente **vue** tiene un código estructurado diferente al tuyo. En tu caso deberías aplicar el **css** del siguiente modo (los nombres de las clases que he puesto son solo para una más fácil identificación de los elementos):

```
 <v-card-actions class="px-0 contendor-card">
                <v-btn small color="blue-grey" class="white--text botonAbajo" @click='funcion(t)'> <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon></v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
```

CSS:

```
.contendor-card {
       position: relative;
    }
.botonAbajo {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0;
    }
```

De este modo daras una posición concreta al botón. Al emplear el **position:relative** para el contenedor y poseriormente **position:absolute** sobre el elemento que deseas colocar en un punto concreto, puedes jugar con sus coordenadas x/y dentro del elemento que lo contiene. Esto lo haces en este caso con la propiedad de css **bottom: 0**.